# Integrate a vector field over a open dome using the divergence theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-theorem

I want to evaluate $$\iint_S\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf S$$ where S is the top half of a unit sphere $S =\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2+z^2\leq1, z\geq0\}$ and the vector field
$$\mathbf F = \langle xz^2,\; \frac 1 3 y^3 + \arctan(z),\; x^2z+y^2 \rangle.$$

The way i figured i would approach this is i would seal the open dome with a unit disc $D =\{(x,y,0): x^2+y^2\leq1\}$ in the $xy$ plane so that it forms a simple solid $K$ region that i can calculate using the divergence theorem like this

$$\iint_S\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf S + \iint_D\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf S = \iiint_{K}\text{div}(\mathbf F)\, dV$$
$$\iint_S\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf S = - \iint_D\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf S + \iiint_{K}\text{div}(\mathbf F)\, dV$$

Parameterizing the volume using spherical coordinates i get

$$\text{div}(\mathbf F) = z^2+y^2+x^2 = r^2$$
$$\text{spherical  correction term} = r^2 \sin \phi$$
$$
\iiint_{K}\text{div}(\mathbf F)\, dV=
\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 {r^2 \; r^2 \sin \phi \; dr \; d\theta \; d\phi} =
\frac {2 \pi} 5
$$

and parameterizing the disc using polar coordinates i get
$$\iint_D\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf S = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 {\mathbf F(p(r, \theta)) \cdot normal \; dr \; d\theta}$$
$$p(r, \theta) = \langle r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta, 0 \rangle$$
$$normal = \langle 0, 0, r \rangle$$
$$\mathbf F(p(r, \theta)) \cdot normal = (r \sin \theta)^2 \; r $$
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 {(r \sin \theta)^2 \; r \; dr \; d\theta} = \frac \pi 4$$

So the sum of the disc and dome is
$$ \frac {2 \pi} 5 - \frac \pi 4 = \frac {3 \pi} {20}$$

But the answer should be $\frac {13 \pi} {20}$ so where am i going wrong. I have double checked all the calculations of the integrals so im fairly certain that is not the problem. I have also tried other similar problems but i always get the wrong answer so i assume there is something im missing.

Comment: You mean $\iint_S \mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf S = \iint_S \mathbf F\cdot\mathbf n\,dS$. Check orientations: You should be adding $\pi/4$, not subtracting.

Comment: How did you get $div \mathbf{F}=r^2$? Is that $y^3$ in the second term, or $y^2$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Of cource the normal have to always point in the same direction for the solid, thank you.

Comment: @Andrei You are correct, it is a typo, i will edit it

Comment: @lmapler In order to apply the divergence theorem,  the simple solid region have to be oriented  by **outward-pointing normals**. Your normal along $D$ is pointing in the opposite direction and therefore you have to change the sign of the flux thru $D$. Then we get $\frac {2 \pi} 5 + \frac \pi 4 = \frac {13 \pi} {20}$